# Weird behaviour with change event in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a struts tag like this

```
<s:select label="Select Item" name="select3ph3meter1" id="select3ph3meter1" 
    headerKey="0" headerValue="-- Please Select --" list="meterHeaderList"
    required="true" onchange="show_3ph3meter1(this.value)"  />
```

The problem is it is not calling the above function on `change` event. It works when I change the code to this:

```
... onchange="alert('calling')"
```

I can't understand what's happening here.

Here is the JavaScript function:

```
function show_3ph3meter1(select3ph3meter1) {
    $("#3ph3meter1").load("meterFiller3p31.action",{select3ph3meter1:select3ph3meter1});
}

function show_depotReceipts(selectrecitem) {
    $("#recQuantity").load("depotRecQ.action",{selectrecitem:selectrecitem});
    $("#recRange").load("depotRecRange.action",{selectrecitem:selectrecitem});
}
```

The adjacent function is working perfectly so I assume there is no JavaScript error.

Also, when I put in another function (for instance the adjacent function name in `onchange`), it is also working. The problem may be with this particular function name `show_3ph3meter1()`.

Comment: probably this is not a struts problem at all. I still cannot figure this out.

Comment: in fire bug, there is no change happening on change event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if you have some other java script written over there contains errors , this code wont work.

So better have like this

```
<select class="style" onchange="//do something like this
 //var e = document.getElementById('selectelement'); //if (e) e.value=100;" />
```

please check in IE browsers to get the java script errors. **write entire code in that change event**

Comment: when I put onchange="alert(this.value)" ... it alerts the real value

Comment: your final suggestion may be the only option i got

Answer (score 0):

1. First check your calling function name
2. if this is correct then just write

   onchange="javascript : show_3ph3meter1(this)"

and get value on the function

3 else try the access value in function with selector

```
var elem = document.getElementById("short_code"),
selectedNode = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex]; 
var valu = selectedNode.value;
```

Comment: onchange="javascript : show_3ph3meter1(this.value)" 
also nothing happens

Comment: function is not calling at all.. not even giving error says that function cannot found